# How to split Set<String> in Java or Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, hashset

```
private SharedPreferences sharedpre = null;
private SharedPreferences.Editor saveuser = null;

Set<String> pathNamesImage = new HashSet<String>();
saveuser = sharedpre.edit();

pathNamesImage.add(pathLocal);
saveuser.putStringSet("prePathNames", pathNamesImage);
```

In the above code, I would like to get each string by `split()` method or any other method as per its size. Since all the values are in `Set`. 
 I am not able to get each values like using `split()` method for array. So, can anybody help me please.

Comment: Why you want to use Set and perform split and why not just array/List so when you put element into you check for duplication?

Comment: @almasshaikh Since am using shared preference for saving and retriving values in another activity and splitting it in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the `Set<String>` to an `String[]`, than you can loop over all the entries like this:

```
Set<String> pathNamesImage = new HashSet<String>();

// Initialize a string array to hold all your set entries
String[] stringArray= new String[pathNamesImage.size()];

// Now, you can iterate over Set, by using the array
for(String str : pathNamesImage.toArray(stringArray)){
    Log.d("yeah", "str:" + str);        
}
```

**NOTE**: I see you are using `SharedPreferences` and `StringSet`... Be aware of this nasty issue when modifying a `StringSet` in your `SharedPreferences`:

> [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet(java.lang,String,%20java.util.Set))
>
> Note that you must not modify the set instance returned by this call.
>   The consistency of the stored data is not guaranteed if you do, nor is
>   your ability to modify the instance at all.